# Electron API change for Tray resulting in Exception

Tags: node.js, macos, electron, macos-sierra

The following code

```
let appTray = new Tray(null)
let contextMenu = null
app.on('ready', () => {
    contextMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(menuTemplate)
    appTray.setTitle(defaultTitle)
    appTray.setContextMenu(contextMenu)
})
```

gives out the following error :

```
App threw an error during load
TypeError: Error processing argument at index 0, conversion failure from null
at TypeError (native)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anmol.j/Personal/jam/index.js:23:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
at loadApplicationPackage (/Users/anmol.j/Personal/jam/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:280:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/anmol.j/Personal/jam/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:322:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

I am on MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

Answer (score 0):

The Tray class expects a path to an image during its instantiation, [check out its documentation](http://electron.atom.io/docs/all/#new-trayimage).

> tray = new Tray('/path/to/my/icon')